# Why would this SQL tell me that "FROM keyword not found where expected"?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, toad

This sql in code:

```
SELECT QHR, 
DECODE(DUCKBILLID1,NULL,' ',DUCKBILLID1) "DB1", 
DECODE(DUCKBILLID2,NULL,' ',DUCKBILLID2) "DB2", 
DECODE(DUCKBILLID3,NULL,' ',DUCKBILLID3) "DB3" 
FROM PLATYPUSSCHEDULE 
WHERE PLATYPUSID = :ABCID AND DOW = :DOW
```

...fails with "*FROM keyword not found where expected*"

The same exact thing (except that the quotes around DBN are single quotes in c# code and double quotes, AS SHOWN ABOVE, in TOAD) works just fine in TOAD.

Comment: where are you getting the error? in C# or TOAD?

Comment: See Sharp, yeah (I wish I could have just written "C#" and been done with it)

Comment: I just tried running `select Foo 'f' from Table` in Oracle and I get the same error message.  You need to use double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Yeah, 2quotes in Oracle works fine; it's C# that's being problematic

Comment: You don't really need the quotes around your column aliases. Just leave them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# I'd expect to see something like

```
String qry = 
@"SELECT QHR,  
DECODE(DUCKBILLID1,NULL,' ',DUCKBILLID1) ""DB1"",  
DECODE(DUCKBILLID2,NULL,' ',DUCKBILLID2) ""DB2"",  
DECODE(DUCKBILLID3,NULL,' ',DUCKBILLID3) ""DB3""  
FROM PLATYPUSSCHEDULE  
WHERE PLATYPUSID = :ABCID AND DOW = :DOW";
```

or

```
String qry = 
"SELECT QHR,DECODE(DUCKBILLID1,NULL,' ',DUCKBILLID1) \"DB1\",DECODE(DUCKBILLID2,NULL,' ',DUCKBILLID2) \"DB2\",DECODE(DUCKBILLID3,NULL,' ',DUCKBILLID3) \"DB3\" FROM PLATYPUSSCHEDULE WHERE PLATYPUSID = :ABCID AND DOW = :DOW";
```

I certainly wouldn't expect to see single and double quotes swapped over.

Comment: You need to double up your quotes after `@`. Neither sample will compile.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to escape your quotes (`\"`)

Comment: Sometimes using 's instead of "s makes it easier.